# How to set tag to Google Map's marker in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to set **onInfoWindowClickListener** for each marker that hit the related API according to the **POJO id**. That's what I found for setting onInfoWindowClick event.

```
googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

But I need to set **related pojo ids** as tags to **related markers** before I do `googleMap.addMarker(marker)`. But there is no such thing as `marker.setTag()`. 
How could I put my ID without setting tag?

Comment: Use `HashMap` and store `marker Id` and `Pojo Id`

Comment: how to get marker id?

Comment: there is no marker.setID("") , marker.getID() , too.. :3

Comment: I have another way. Just create `HashMap` with both with your main `Marker` and another one with `POJO Class`. and get back your `POJO` based on Particular `Marker` on `getInfoContents(.....)`

Comment: great.., lemme try this.

Comment: I think you're right. It should work. But I'm facing another problem. My infowindowclicklistener didn't work so far.

Comment: pls post your code what ever you implemented

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102582/discussion-between-cristy-yg-and-m-d).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have one way. Just create `HashMap` with both your main `Marker` and another one with `POJO Class` and get back your `POJO Class` based on Particular `Marker`  clicked on `getInfoContents(.....)`

Answer (score 85):

Now You can do like this

Update your google play service version to

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0

Marker marker=mMap.addmarker(new MarkerOptions(LatLang));
// set object as tag
marker.setTag(your object)

// to retrieve the marker
marker.getTag();// Type cast to your object type;
```

Comment: Updating `Google Play Services` did it for me. I however had an error after changing the version to 9.4.0 with `gradle` sync. I had to close `Android Studio`, open `SDK Manager`, Update `Google Repository`. After that `gradle` sync worked.

Comment: This is a great answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Try to call setTag() method on map marker, not on the MarkerOptions object for.e.g.,

```
private void addMk(LatLng latLng, String title, String snips,String tagId) {
 MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .title(title)
                .snippet(snips);
        
                 googleMap                 //Google googleMap object for map reference
                .addMarker(options)
                .setTag(tagId);

    }

googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              
               String tagId= String.valueOf(marker.getTag());
                Log.d(TAG, "onInfoWindowClick: TAG_ID "+tagId);
        }
    });
```

Hope, this works!