# How to include ID in marker in addition to title and snippet

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-markers

when addMarker in map android studio, i can only be input title and snippet.
How to add other parameters such as id?
Which I can later get when clicking on the marker.

```
private void addMarker(LatLng latlng, final String title, final String deskripsi, final String id) {
   markerOptions.position(latlng);
   markerOptions.title(title);
   markerOptions.snippet(deskripsi);

   gMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

   gMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
   @Override
       public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), marker.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use one Hashmap for storing marker and ids

```
   private HashMap<Marker, Integer> markerIdMapping = new HashMap<>();


 private void addMarker(LatLng latlng, final String title, final String deskripsi, final String id) {
        markerOptions.position(latlng);
        markerOptions.title(title);
        markerOptions.snippet(deskripsi);

        Marker marker = gMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        markerIdMapping.put(marker, id);

        gMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), marker.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                String markerId = markerIdMapping.get(marker);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: how to include more than 1 ID?

Comment: You can use array of integers in value part of hash map
like  HashMap<Marker, Integer[]> markerIdMapping = new HashMap<>();

Answer (score 1):

You can use `#marker.setTag`

Ex :

```
Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
marker.setTag([You can give here]); // marker.setTag(30)
```

Later you can get using `getTag`

```
int id = (int) marker.getTag();
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to add other parameters such as id?

What other fields do you want to be set apart from the marker id?

Marker id is autogenerated when we create a marker using `GoogleMap.addMarker`. What you can do is after the marker is created, use a `HashMap` to map all marker id's and inside `getInfoWindow(Marker marker)` or `getInfoContents(Marker marker)` use the `marker.getId()` to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

To uniquely identify your marker, use :

```
setTag(Object obj)
```

and to retrieve, use:

```
getTag()
```

see the answer posted here:
[How to set tag to Google Map's marker in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35197237/how-to-set-tag-to-google-maps-marker-in-android)